# Preview file from memory in flutter windows app

Tags: windows, flutter, filestream, preview, flutter-windows

Is there a way to preview/open with the default app, a file from memory without creating a temporary file in the disc, on a Flutter Windows Desktop app?

(One example would be a ContentProvider/PipeProvider in Android)

We are trying to preview files that are encrypted, and creating a temporary file in disc would defeat the purpose.